# The payment is not confirmed

Tags: blockchain

am using blockchain.info.

I have made a bitcoin transaction of 2.36 BTC to the address 1Lokb2a2ZLCYrYfUTT2bEwc9wJe3Cidi4Z

You can see the transaction at https://blockchain.info/tx/eb198bb925379b8381ec43bdc094fb396eda2136940957bf1a2c11866507a20d

I have paid a 0.0002431 fee but it has been almost 30 hours and it still shows "Unconfirmed".

What could be the error? Also, more importantly, how do I cancel the unconfirmed transaction and get back my coins?

Comment: There is a huge [backlog](https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions) at the moment. Don't worry, just need to be patient.